# How do I concatenate a variable with a greeting

Tags: javascript

### My problem:

I have been learning to program on khan academy and I am having trouble *concatenating* a *variable* with a *greeting*, it keeps saying I am *concatenating a string* instead.

### What I have done so far:

```
var drawGabby = function(){ 
  var nameX = random(0, 300);
  var nameY = random(0, 300);
  var yourName = "gabby";
  fill(255, 0, 0); 
  textSize(30); 
  text("Hiiii, " +"gabby",nameX, nameY);
}; 
drawGabby();
```

### Question:

I have tried looking for the answer on google but I do not understand the variables they are using can someone please explain how to do it properly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your string is "Hello".
Let's set up a variable that contains a string just for this example.
Let's call our variable name.
We will use the keyword var to declare the variable.

var name = "Joe";

Now let's concatenate

"Hello " + name

This would return: "Hello Joe".

You may wonder why storing the name in a variable instead of just making another string. If you change the content of the name variable --var name = "Julie" for example -- you would not have to change anything when you concatenate. You could just keep "Hello " + name where "Hello" is a string and name is a variable.
You may also wonder why I left a space after Hello --"Hello " NOT "Hello". If I had not left a space, the output would be "HelloJoe". 
I hope this helps.

PS: Think about your comma before your name variables. When you concatenate, you need a + sign. Your commas are not needed here.